# Amortized Analysis Example on Empty List

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

We want to have a set of `n` linear list to doing following operation:

`Insert(x,i)` : insert new elemets `x` on list `i`, and cost of this operation is `1`.

`Sum(i) :` calculate sum of all elements in list `i` and replace whole elements of list with the calculated `sum`, and cost is equal to number of elements in list `i` when we using this operation.

if we start with empty list and do the above operation in arbitrary manner, what is the amortized cost of each operation :

```
1)insert : 2, sum : 1
2)insert : 1, sum : 2
3)insert : 1, sum : n
4)insert : n, sum : 1
```

who can help me to understand how to solve this example and what's the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The amortized cost of all operations here is `O(1)`:

1. The `insert` operation has an `O(1)` time complexity according to the problem statement.
2. The `sum` operation has an `O(1)` amortized time complexity because each element is processed only once(after that it is replaced with the result of the `sum` query and is not used anymore).

Comment: @MaryamGhizh O(2) is O(1).

Comment: @MaryamGhizh Because O(2) and O(1) is the same thing.

Comment: we didn't talk about O(). we want to calculate amortized analysis is 2 or 1

Comment: @kraskevich, can i talk to you in chat about this question ?

Comment: @user4249446 It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is True,

Hint:

The aggregate time for d deallocateNode operations is O(d) , and the amortized complexity of deallocateNode is O(d/d) = O(1) . Consequently, the actual complexity of a sequence of a allocateNode and d deallocateNode operations is O(a+d).

you can use potential method.